# Google Maps can't read property 'extend' of undefined after page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to increase page speed by loading my Google Maps two seconds after page load. While doing so, I keep on getting "Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined". I know there is some asynchronous loading going on but I'm not sure how to get it in proper order to get this map to load 2 seconds after the page is done. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Page Code:**

```
<div id="mapCont"></div>
<script defer type='text/javascript' src='/js/maps.js'></script>
```

**maps.js**

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key', function()
{

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        function doMap(callback) {
            $("#mapCont").html('<div id="mapInfoManual" class="searchMap mb5"></div>');
        callback();
        }
        
        doMap(function() {

        initialize();
          
         var map = null;
         var markers = [];
         var openedInfoWindow ="";
         var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   
         function initialize() {
   
             var mapOptions = {
   
              zoom: 8,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(64.85599578876611, -147.83363628361917),
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
               mapTypeControl: true,
               mapTypeControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
               },
               zoomControl: true,
               zoomControlOptions: {
                   style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
               }
             };
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapInfoManual"),
                 mapOptions);
   
   
             google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                 zoomChangeBoundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                     if (this.getZoom() > 20) // Change max/min zoom here
                         this.setZoom(18);
   
                     google.maps.event.removeListener(zoomChangeBoundsListener);
                 });
         });
             addMarker();
           }
   
   
         function addMarker() {
   
               var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
               for (i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
                 CodeAddress(markersArray[i]);
               }
             }
   
             // Address To Marker
             function CodeAddress(markerEntry) {
             var mytitle = (markersArray[i]['title']);
                     var myaddress = (markersArray[i]['address']);
                     var linkid = (markersArray[i]['linkid']);
                     var linkurl = (markersArray[i]['linkurl']);
                   var image = { url: '/images/MapPin.png', };
             var lat = markerEntry['lat'];
             var long = markerEntry['long'];
             // var myLatLng = {lat: markerEntry['lat'], lng: markerEntry['long']};
             var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(long));
   
                     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: myLatlng,
                       map: map,
                       icon: image
                     });
                     bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
                     var infoWindowContent = "<div class='cityMapInfoPop'><span style='font-weight:700;'>"+ mytitle +"</span><br /><br />" + myaddress + "<br /><br /><a href='/center/" + linkurl + "/'>More Details</a></div>";
                     openInfoWindow(marker, infoWindowContent);
                     markers.push(marker);
                     map.fitBounds(bounds);
               }
               //Info Window
   
             function openInfoWindow(marker, infoWindowContent) {
               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: '<div class="cityMapInfoPop">' + infoWindowContent + '</div>'
               });
   
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   
                 if (openedInfoWindow != "") {
                   openedInfoWindow.close();
                 }
   
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
                 openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
               });
             }
   
    });
    }, 2000);
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key` loads additional scripts that are not being captured by your implementation. The package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader, enables the following pattern and is probably what you want:

```js
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "",
  version: "weekly",
  libraries: ["places"]
});

loader
  .load()
  .then(() => {
    doMap();
    initialize();
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // do something
  });
```

Alternative(use callback) if you want JQuery and your existing pattern:

```js
window.callback = () => {
  doMap();
  initialize();
};

$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=callback', () => {}); // do nothing here
```

Also related: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/programmatic-load-button